# android searchview how show same image

Tags: android, android-search

```
<android.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:title="Search aaaa"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/widget_store_promotions_header_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

result :[image][image]

how show searchview same bellow :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use this setting in your searchview xml

```
android:queryHint="your hint"
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

by using `android:iconifiedByDefault="false"` the searchview shows the edit text also

Comment: thank.can you help me again. when touch searchview,auto hide queryHint.

Comment: sure write a searchview on click listener and inside that write the hiding code. but the hint will go away after you type something which is how it should be done